# How do we allocate to local memory in Ctree within a kernel function

Tags: python, opencl

How do we use the `__local` OpenCL identifier when writing code in Ctree using Python? We're trying to do the following:

```
__local int *some_array[WORK_GROUP_SIZE];
```

Except with Ctree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how the [stencil specializer](http://github.com/ucb-sejits/stencil_code) in the file stencil_code/backend/ocl.py handles that.  The third parameter passed to the kernel function is a reference to the workgroup local memory space.

```
def visit_FunctionDecl(self, node):
    ...
    node.params[-1].set_global()
    node.params[-1].type = ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)()
    node.params.append(SymbolRef('block', ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)()))
    node.params[-1].set_local()
    node.defn = node.defn[0]
    ...
    return node
```

The code that constructs the c routine that calls this kernel is in the same function, your local_mem_size calculation should be less complicated than appears here.  It's a little hard to follow but it builds the local_memory reference for the set_arg call as follows

```
    local_mem_size = reduce(
        operator.mul,
        (size + 2 * self.kernel.ghost_depth[index]
         for index, size in enumerate(local_size)),
        ct.sizeof(cl.cl_float())
    )
    setargs.append(
        clSetKernelArg(
            'kernel', len(arg_cfg) + 1,
            local_mem_size,
            NULL()
        )
    )
```

Hope this helps